# Pushing to nuget.org with dotnet returns 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to publish a new version of my nuget package to nuget.org. However for some reason several times, now, it returns an internal server error.

This is my command:

`dotnet nuget push J:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\Just.Another.Nuget\output\Just.Another.Nuget.1.4.1.nupkg -k <myAPIkey> -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

the output is:

```
info : Pushing Just.Another.Nuget.1.4.1.nupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
info :   InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1963ms
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
info :   InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1265ms
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
info :   InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 549ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

I'm trying to capture the packets to look at them but I'm completely new to it. Tried some Wireshark but finding out what to capture was harder than getting Microsoft Message Analyzer and filtering by the PID of the PowerShell process where I'm executing the above command.

Any help, including what to look at in the packets, is appreciated!

EDIT:

Nevermind, posting a put through Postman to "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/" led me to "https://status.nuget.org/" which, currently, states package upload is Degraded. If when it is fixed my problem is solved I'll post an answer.